# How to create AppDomain with special permission restrictions

Tags: c#, razor, appdomain

I want to create a sandbox in my project, so I wrote some test code.

But it seems hard for me to create AppDomain with special permission restrictions.

Here is my code, is anyone who can help me out?

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var appDomain = CreateAppDomain();
        using (var service = new IsolatedTemplateService(() => appDomain))
        {
           // string template = @"<div>Hello @Model.Name</div>";
            string template = @"<div>Hello @Model.Name   @{         System.IO.File.CreateText(@""c:\\work\\c.txt"");}</div>";
            var model = new Person { Name = "Matt" };

            string result = service.Parse(template, model, null, null);
            Response.Write(result);

        }

        return View();
    }

    private AppDomain CreateAppDomain()
    {
        var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        permissionSet.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
        permissionSet.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

        var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
        .First(x => x.GetName().Name == "RazorEngine")
        .Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();

        return AppDomain.CreateDomain("RazorTestHost", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Evidence,
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation, permissionSet, assemblies);
    }

}
```